# Redirect external URL Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to redirect to an external URL, i'm developing on localhost so i am getting localhost:4200/www.example.com, how can i solve this? thanks in advance

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html'
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    public title: string;

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){
        window.location.href = 'www.example.com'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are miss http

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'
```